# Populate multiple cities in a single dropdown

Tags: jquery, angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap

In angularjs using bootstrap/jQuery/html5, I want to populate a city based on state and populate, in turn based on country in a single dropdown. When cites come up, I want to select multiple cites. How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: It's very easy. But you didn't post any code, so unlikely someone will be willing to spend more the 10 seconds on this question.

Comment: Basically i am fresher in angularjs so if anyone help me for this it will be thankful to him.

Comment: Again: you didn't ask a question, didn't describe any problem. It makes this question pretty unanswerable.

Comment: You can use HTML and bootstrap css to acheive this. Take a look at this link http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/multi-level-dropdown-menu-bs3

Answer (score 0):

nested dropdown is what you are looking for:
http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/multi-level-dropdown-menu-bs3

I hope you do have the data of all countries with their states and cities. For multi select you need another jquery plugin

http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-Multiple-Select-Plugin-For-Bootstrap-Bootstrap-Multiselect.html

Use whichever is effective for your requirement.